# How to compare two vectors for equality?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have the following program:

```
std::vector<int> nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> nums2 = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

bool equal = std::equal(nums.begin(), nums.end(), nums2.begin());
if (equal)
{
    cout << "Both vectors are equal" << endl;
}
```

There are two vectors that have equal elements. std::equal function does not work here because it goes sequentially and compares corresponding elements. Is there a way to check that both these vectors are equal and get true in my case without sorting? In real example I do not have integers but custom objects which comparing as equality of pointers.

Comment: Either sort the vectors or use a `std::unordered_set` - are these options?

Comment: Yes this can work, thanks, but maybe there is some stl algorithm for that?

Comment: What result do you seek if there are duplicate elements.  For example, would `{1,2,3,4,4}` compare equal to `{4,3,2,1}` by your criterion?

Comment: Thanks to everyone, it was really helpfull. Actually the algorithm is_permutation() is exaclty what I was looking for. Performance does not matter in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a `std::unordered_set` from each vector, then compare those, as shown in the code snippet below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>  
#include <vector>  
#include <unordered_set> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> nums2 = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    std::vector<int> nums3 = { 5, 4, 9, 2, 1 };

    std::unordered_set<int> s1(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    std::unordered_set<int> s2(nums2.begin(), nums2.end());
    std::unordered_set<int> s3(nums3.begin(), nums3.end());

    if (s1 == s2) {
        std::cout << "1 and 2 are equal";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "1 and 2 are different";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if (s1 == s3) {
        std::cout << "1 and 3 are equal";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "1 and 3 are different";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, there are some points to bear in mind:

1. For vectors of custom type objects, you would need to provide an `operator==` for that type (but that would have to be done anyway, or how can you say if the two *vectors* have the same contents).
2. Vectors that containing duplicate entries will create sets that have those duplicates removed: Thus, `{1, 2, 2, 3}` will show equal to `{1, 2, 3}`.
3. You will also need to provide a `std:hash` for your custom type. For a trivial class, `bob`, which just wraps an integer, that hash, and the required `operator==`, could be defined as shown below; you can then replace the `<int>` specializations in the above example with `<bob>` and it will work. (This [cppreference article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) explains more about the hash.)

```cpp
class bob {
public:
    int data;
    bob(int arg) : data{ arg } { }
};
bool operator==(const bob& lhs, const bob& rhs)
{
    return lhs.data == rhs.data;
}
template<> struct std::hash<bob> {
    std::size_t operator()(bob const& b) const noexcept {
        return static_cast<size_t>(b.data);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this is exactly what I need.

Comment: You also need a way to hash custom objects.

Comment: There is [std::unordered_multiset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset) that doesn't remove duplicates.

Comment: @Arty Yes - I saw that but the linked cppreference page also notes that `std::equal_to` is **not available** for `std::unordered_multiset`; however, there ***is*** an `operator==`  but it's not clear to me how that would work.

Comment: @Arty I suppose the OP could add a check that both vectors have the same `.size()` - but that would still leave issues for cases like `{1, 2, 2, 3}` and `{1, 2, 3, 3}`.

Comment: As simple [test shows](https://tio.run/##fY07DsMgEER7TrFSGpCcInHnYK4SEUAJEj/BUlk@OyG4cJcpVpqdpxmV0lU5Gd6tXWxQrmoDvIaYtclGP4tBQc7AxoLZSC@IDQhe2kAZbAS6CuplUbEicH6YV4xOuvSR/TOQn@iIzgFfHdq@wnuhoNs8wW2Ce787g3WF//SBzoNmD7K39gU) just using `==` is enough for multiset and works correctly!

Comment: As one [can see](https://tio.run/##fY4xCsMwDEV3n0LQxYZ0aLOlxlcJru22BkdKE3kKObtrEmg6VYNA7z/Qd@N4dsnis5RTRJeyD6Az0uTDFHw/BzbiCCLNPAU7/LJHRseR0CYjIjIMNqJUsAioM7PvOkeZQev9uBMlm8aXrWRTvlp4Z5t6Jm2kkhs5egw5caxldP1g5NI2cGngWveqGvjv7mK7ueom1lI@) `equal_to` works also with multiset.

Comment: @Arty Possibly. However, just because something works in a particular test case, doesn't mean it will always work. The warning given about unstable iterator order should not be ignored.

Comment: @AdrianMole I can't imagine that multiset implements `==` operator while it may give wrong result sometimes, probably it will be a disaster for users of multiset. Usually if some operator can't be implemented so that it gives correct results always then standard library usually removes such operator (doesn't implement it). Also as I read [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset/operator_cmp) there is nothing said that it not always correct.It only says it will be undefined if elements are not correctly hashable and equality comparable,is not the case for OP's `int`

Answer (score 3):

The [`std::is_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation) standard library algorithm does exactly what you want. It returns `true` if both ranges contain the same elements in any order.

It *might* be slow for some applications but it only requires equality comparison and it doesn't require a temporary container or additional memory allocation.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> nums2 = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    bool equal = std::is_permutation(nums.begin(), nums.end(), nums2.begin(), nums2.end());

    if (equal) {
        std::cout << "Both vectors are equal" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) or a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Multiset). C++ standard library does have implementations of these data structures:

- [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)
- [std::multiset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)
- [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)
- [std::unordered_multiset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset)

Comment: For this I have to overload operator greater that for custom object. This will not work for me because I do not have any criteria for comparison. Is there a way to compare sequentially objects without sorting it?

Comment: @Oleg Use `unordered_set` or `unordered_multiset`. They need you to specialize `std::hash` and overload equality operator.

Comment: @Oleg vector is really not the right tool there. This is exactly the domain of a set data structure. Especially if you have a lot of objects in those containers.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to invent an algorithm to do this from scratch, because for whatever reason using sets or sorts doesn't work, I would consider removing matches. This will be inefficient - it's O(n^2) - but it will *work*, and inefficiency is unlikely to be an issue in many cases:

```
bool compare(A, B)
  copy B to BB
  for each a in A
    if BB contains a
      remove a from BB
    else
      return false

  if BB is empty
    return true

  return false
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I just wanted to make this with some stl algorithms but this is what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing-in one more way to solve your task, using [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). It also works correctly if vectors have duplicate elements (as seen from example below). It is also quite fast, `O(N*Log(N))` time on average, in real life will be close in time to solutions with std::unordered_set or std::unordered_multiset.

Yes, I see that OP asked to achieve without sorting, but actually std::is_permutation is also doing sorting underneath almost for sure. And std::set does indirectly sorting too using trees. Even std::unordered_set does a kind of sorting by hash value (hash bucketing is a kind of radix sorting). So probably this task can't be solved without a kind of indirect sorting or other kind of ordering whole vector.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BDoMgEETvfsUmvUBCTcR6sei/IBIlQTCCvRi/3SI2tU27J3bmzSxiHK9Cc9Nt20UZoedWAuO6s5Py/VAnp/iQwtvpU1HW@UnyQCXKeBi4MgjDkkAY59uyPCIsmDWYeXAZVLBkBCiBnMCNQHgXK4ke3b0iqnk0ApSt97PM2cmj2JI2sttPHcEslaZFGP9D6TdKf1FhZw@MHUtjreZ67PmuoNePqyOK31To0Pdk3bYn)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> nums1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5}, nums2 = {5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1};
    std::sort(nums1.begin(), nums1.end());
    std::sort(nums2.begin(), nums2.end());
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (nums1 == nums2) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: `std::is_permutation` doesn't modify the data so there's no sorting. That's why it has O(n^2) worst case complexity. That's also why I added the caveat about speed but it works and is almost certainly "fast enough" for many uses.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Interesting how it achieves its task? It is said it has complexity ranging from O(N^2) to O(N). Is there somewhere algorithm for it? Also does standard restrict different compilers to implement it in O(N^2) time? I don't see in standard that it says how it should be implemented. Can't some compilers do just sorting in temporary memory?

Comment: Cppreference has a [possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation). You can also look at the major library implementations, here's [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L3524), Micsrosoft's implementation [starts here](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/algorithm#L980).

Comment: I think the algorithm goes back to Alex Stepanov, there's some [info here in his note](http://stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf).

Comment: If you're interested in the design of the standard library algorithms most of the credit goes to Alexander Stepanov, he's written several good books about generic programming.